# How can we synchronize Nodes from Staging to Production Server

Tags: 7, nodes, staging

My Question is there any way we can track the node changes on Staging Server and Push the same to the Production Server. Best use case will be,

- Customer does not want to change the content on Production server.
- He wants to first change on Staging server get it tested and push the content to live server.
- Have revisions for changes so that he can revert back any time using node re- visioning system !

Can we do this maintaining the node id's same across staging and live servers ? Is there any out of the box solution for this like feature module does for configuration changes tracked using modules?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Node changes, you can use [node export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export)  module to migrate node between drupal installations. for Tracking Configurations changes there is another module [configurations](http://drupal.org/project/configuration) , i haven't tried yet. Be sure cos the module release is still in dev

Comment: I don't think node export will track node id's between different environments! It will just help to export import content. And does, it solve content update problem from staging to production ?

Comment: node_export leverages the UUID module so nids can be different between systems.

Answer (score 2):

Helpful conversation [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/deploying-content-updates-from-staging-server-to-live-server).

You could also check the [Deploy module](http://drupal.org/project/deploy)

> The Deploy module is designed to allow developers to easily stage Drupal content from one site to another. Deploy automatically manages dependencies between objects (like node references). It is designed to have a rich API which can be easily extended to be used in a variety of situations.