# Staging / testing environment

Tags: testing, staging

I've started a big project and need to create some kind of staging area or testing environment, where I'm able to start off with developing the site and after launch will be able to use as the server where I'm able to add new features etc.

I've tried searching around, but haven't found a satisfying solution yet.

So I was hoping someone here could guide me through how to start off my Drupal adventure. Setting up a testing environment, which in the end I'll be able to push to a live server and then use it just for coding new features and push them live later.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Unfortunately, I have to close this.  The topic of dev to staging to production is a huge topic that can't be adequately addressed in our question/answer format.  It is also an area where Drupal is making progress, but is still lacking.

Comment: Can't believe they won't even *allow* people to even *try* to answer this very important question about something that is known to be very difficult in Drupal. Essentially, the standard setup is two (or more) separate Drupal installs, with their own code base and databases, and version control on the code via Git or SVN. The tricky thing then is database migrations (particularly, content migrations) between the sites - solutions to this often involve the module Features; see [this q](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1335) and [also this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137/)

Comment: actually [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/how-to-migrate-from-test-environment-to-production-environment?rq=1) seems to have the best explanation